# How can i add register link in the top links in magento

Tags: magento

I have to add Register link in the top menu links

So i did this, but i dont know whats the helper for register. Please help me

```
   <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>


    <customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Register</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>Register</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        </reference>
        <remove name="wishlist_sidebar"></remove>
        <remove name="reorder"></remove>
    </customer_logged_out>
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're after here.  Could you explain more what you're trying to do and why you want "helper for register"?  Explaining that might make it clearer what you're after.

Comment: I want to add Register page link in the top as like login page link in the top,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `customer/getRegisterUrl` as your helper to get the registration URL. This means that Magento do something like this:

```
$helper = Mage::helper("customer"); // gets Mage_Customer_Helper_Data
$url = $helper->getRegisterUrl();
```

Hope that helps.

Thanks,
Joe

Answer (score 14):

What you were doing is almost correct, but instead of `customer/getAccountUrl` you should use `customer/getRegisterUrl`.

So basically you should add the following xml line in `customer_logged_out\reference`

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Register</label><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/><title>Register</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
```

So your code will look like this:

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>


<customer_logged_out>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Register</label><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/><title>Register</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
    <remove name="wishlist_sidebar"></remove>
    <remove name="reorder"></remove>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score -2):

```
<action method="addLink" 
    translate="label title" 
    module="customer">
    <label>
         Register
    </label>
    <url helper="customer/getCreateUrl"/>
    <title>Register</title>
    <prepare/>
    <urlParams/>
    <position>100</position>
</action>
```

Comment: Try and put a little description in your answers and format your code snippet correctly.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am down-voting this. I cannot find the `customer/getCreateUrl` function. If it works for you, this is probably because you had some extension installed.